# Дяди или дядья?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мне попадалось и так, и так? И все-таки, как же во множественном числе будет "дядя": "дяди" или "дядья"? Или второе относится только к родственникам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во множественном числе литературная норма - **дяди** (форма родительного падежа - *дядей*). А форма **дядья** - просторечная (в родительном падеже - *дядьёв*).

Answer (score 0):

Не сказал бы, что она такая уж просторечная...
"Дядя" имеет несколько значений. 
В значении "брат отца или матери" может иметь архаичную форму множественного числа "дядья", которая признаётся, например, Лопатиным нормативной наряду с "дяди". Более того, лично мне она кажется предпостительной, но при этом, правда, она совершенно не сочетается с числительными.
Во всех остальных значениях - дяди.